# Get ID by Element Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several text boxes which have drop downs on them. When a user clicks on the field with the drop down class, I want to get the ID of that field. This seems like it should be simple, but I can't quite seem to figure it out...

I have tried:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    alert(this.getElementById);
});
```

Yet this only returns undefined.

Comment: @roasted answer should work, just mixing your jquery and javascript in the same evaluation won't work. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ID is a property of the object, so just use following code:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't think of the proper syntax!

Comment: @BarryTormey For reference, `getElementById` is a method of the `document` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById . It is used to retrieve an element by their `id` property/attribute. You were just looking for the property of an element object you already have (`this`)

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will keep that for future reference. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Wrong syntax.You have to write

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[*Correct Syntax:*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.id?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.id)

```
var idStr = element.id; // Get the id.
element.id = idStr; // Set the id
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `getElementById` incorrectly. It's a function used to get a dom element on your page using an id as filter condition. It's not used to get element id.

Correct usage of `getElementById` is

```
var elem = document.getElementById('theid');
```

You simply have to use

```
alert(this.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want this:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Its simple you can alert the element id with the below code written by me

```
          $(".dropdown").click(function() {

          var id = $('.dropdown').attr('id');
          alert(id);

         });
```